# Output of my quantum circuit to create 3-qubit GHZ-like state does not make sense mathematically

Tags: quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit, ghz-state

I want to create the GHZ-like state, $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|011\rangle - |100 \rangle \right)$.
I build my circuit in the following way.

1. apply the x gate to the first and third qubits to make the input as $|101\rangle$
2. apply the Hadamard gate to the first qubit
3. apply the CNOT gate to (q0,q1) and (q1, q2)
   [image] [image]

I run the simulation to make sure that I get the right reult.
However, I failed to get the expected state mathematically. Here is how I do the calculation:

$(H\otimes I \otimes I)|101\rangle = H|1\rangle \otimes I|0\rangle \otimes I|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|0\rangle - |1\rangle) \otimes |0\rangle \otimes|1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|001\rangle - |101\rangle)$

Apply CNOT gates: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|001\rangle - |101\rangle) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|001\rangle - |111\rangle) \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|001\rangle - |110\rangle)$

My calculation tells me I should input $|110\rangle$ instead :
$(H\otimes I \otimes I)|110\rangle = H|1\rangle \otimes I|1\rangle \otimes I|0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|0\rangle - |1\rangle) \otimes |1\rangle \otimes0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|010\rangle - |110\rangle)$

Apply CNOT gates: $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|010\rangle - |110\rangle) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|010\rangle - |100\rangle) \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|011\rangle - |100\rangle)$

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with qubit ordering convention. Qiskit uses the "little endian" ordering convention where the least significant bit is listed first in a quantum state. Several other software frameworks and textbooks use the opposite "big endian" convention. Try using `QuantumCircuit.reverse_bits()` and you should get the expected answer. If this comment is unclear I can expand on it in an answer.

Comment: https://qiskit.org/documentation/explanation/endianness.html

Comment: @Callum Do you mean I should apply (I x I x H) |101> (x represents tensor product)? I still couldn't get the expected answer. Do you mind to expand on it and explain a bit more in an answer? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Callum I try to change the input to |110> and use qc.revser_bits(). Then I can get the expected state and match my calculation (I updated my post a bit). However, I'm still not really understand how ordering take in play here. Since the original input state |101> is symmetric, which bit is the first bit seems not real significant to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Callum said, your ordering of qubit is wrong. Qiskit keeps the 0th qubit at the rightmost space in a ket representation or for measurement.

If you have, say 3 qubits, qubit#1, qubit#2, qubit#3, in state $|-\rangle_1$,$|1\rangle_2$ and $|+\rangle_3$, respectively, then their joint state is written as $|+_31_2-_1\rangle$ i.e, $|+1-\rangle_{3,2,1}$, where subscript denotes the qubit number for the corresponding state.

For your circuit, state progression will go as follows:

- Your initial state will be $|000\rangle_{3,2,1}$
- Applying $X_1$ will get you $|001\rangle_{3,2,1}$
- Applying $X_3$ to that state will get you $|101\rangle_{3,2,1}$.

I hope the qubit ordering is clear now.

---

As you have asked in your comment, yes, even if $|101\rangle$ is a "symmetric state" as you have said, Applying $H_3$ will give you $|001\rangle - |101\rangle$ and applying $H_1$ will give you $|100\rangle - |101\rangle$.

---

Now, for your circuit, the state will evolve as follows:

$$|000\rangle \xrightarrow{X_1X_3} |101\rangle \xrightarrow{H_1} \frac{|100\rangle-|101\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \xrightarrow{CNOT_{1\rightarrow2}}\frac{|100\rangle-|111\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} \xrightarrow{CNOT_{2\rightarrow3}}\frac{|100\rangle-|011\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}\,,$$

thus, giving you the histogram you have pasted in the question.